# Каким образом в typeorm использовать вложенные запросы в relationship?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Каким образом в typeorm посчитать количество count()[Find Options](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options) В sql вроде костыльно реализовал но в NestJs (

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
findAll() {
    return this.postsRepository.find({
      //relations: ['user', 'images', 'comments', 'likes', 'shares'],
      relations: ['user', 'images'],
    });
  }

@Entity()
export class Post {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  post_text: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.post, { cascade: true })
  user: User[];

  @OneToMany(() => Image, (image) => image.post, { cascade: true })
  images: Image[];

  @OneToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.post, { cascade: true })
  comments: Comment[];

  @OneToMany(() => Like, (like) => like.post, { cascade: true })
  likes: Like[];

  @OneToMany(() => Share, (share) => share.post, { cascade: true })
  shares: Share[];
}
```

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(comment.postId)
        FROM
            comment
        WHERE
            post.id = comment.postId) AS count_comments,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(likes.postId)
        FROM
            likes
        WHERE
            post.id = likes.postId) AS count_likes,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(share.postId)
        FROM
            share
        WHERE
            post.id = share.postId) AS count_shares
FROM
    post
        LEFT JOIN
    user ON post.userId = user.id
        LEFT JOIN
    image ON post.id = image.postId
        LEFT JOIN
    comment ON post.id = comment.postId;
```

```
json api

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "title1",
        "post_text": "text1",
        "created_at": "2021-10-16T13:34:14.247Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-16T13:34:14.247Z",
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "James1",
            "lastName": "Spiegel1",
            "avatar": "default"
        },
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "image_path": "default1"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "image_path": "default1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "title1",
        "post_text": "text1",
        "created_at": "2021-10-16T13:34:15.033Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-16T13:34:15.033Z",
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "James1",
            "lastName": "Spiegel1",
            "avatar": "default"
        },
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "image_path": "default1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "title1",
        "post_text": "text1",
        "created_at": "2021-10-16T13:34:19.087Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-16T13:34:19.087Z",
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "James1",
            "lastName": "Spiegel1",
            "avatar": "default"
        },
        "images": []
    }
]
```